# How to convert JSON data into Kotlin object

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I have a sample here of an existing json,
my issue is i need to convert it into kotlin,
I'm new in kotlin and been reading a lot of tutorial, but
i haven't since samples as complicated as this.

here's the JSON

```
{
"mobile": {
    "id":"1",
    "Device": {
        "Device Name": "Huawei P30 Pro",
        "Price": "10000",
        "rating": "3.4",
        "phone_img_url": "https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/huawei-mate30-pro-.jpg", 
        "Category": "Phablet",
        "Description": {
            "Network": ["GSM", "HSPA", "LTE"],
            "Launch": {
                "Announced Date": "2019, September",
                "Status": "Available. Released 2019, September"
            },
            "Body": {
                "Dimension": "158.1 x 73.1 x 8.8 mm (6.22 x 2.88 x 0.35 in)",
                "Weight": "198 g (6.98 oz)",
                "Build": "Front/back glass (Gorilla Glass 6), aluminum frame",
                "Network": [
                    "Single SIM (Nano-SIM) or Hybrid Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by)", 
                    "IP68 dust/water resistant (up to 1.5m for 30 mins)"],
                "Display":{
                    "Type": "OLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors",
                    "Size": "6.53 inches, 108.7 cm2 (~94.1% screen-to-body ratio)",
                    "Resolution": "1176 x 2400 pixels, 18.5:9 ratio (~409 ppi density)",
                    "Protection": ["Corning Gorilla Glass 6",
                        "DCI-P3",
                        "HDR10"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "id":"2",
    "Device": {
        "Device Name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro",
        "Price": "15000",
        "rating": "3.4",
        "Category": "Phablet",
        "Description": {
            "Network": ["GSM", "HSPA", "LTE"],
            "Launch": {
                "Announced Date": "2019, August",
                "Status": "Available. Released 2019, September"
            },
            "Body": {
                "Dimension": "161.4 x 76.4 x 8.8 mm (6.35 x 3.01 x 0.35 in)",
                "Weight": "200 g (7.05 oz)",
                "Build": "Front/back glass (Gorilla Glass 5)",
                "Network": [
                    "Hybrid Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by)"],
                "Display":{
                    "Type": "IPS LCD capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors",
                    "Size": "6.53 inches, 104.7 cm2 (~84.9% screen-to-body ratio)",
                    "Resolution": "1080 x 2340 pixels, 19.5:9 ratio (~395 ppi density)",
                    "Protection": ["Corning Gorilla Glass 6",
                        "500 nits max brightness",
                        "HDR"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "id":"3",
    "Device": {
        "Device Name": "Huawei P30 Pro",
        "Price": "17000",
        "rating": "3.4",
        "Category": "Phablet",
        "Description": {
            "Network": ["GSM", "HSPA", "LTE"],
            "Launch": {
                "Announced Date": "2019, March",
                "Status": "Available. Released 2019, March"
            },
            "Body": {
                "Dimension": "158 x 73.4 x 8.4 mm (6.22 x 2.89 x 0.33 in)",
                "Weight": "192 g (6.77 oz)",
                "Build": "Front/back glass, aluminum frame",
                "Network": [
                    "Single SIM (Nano-SIM) or Hybrid Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by)", 
                    "IP68 dust/water resistant (up to 2m for 30 mins)"],
                "Display":{
                    "Type": "OLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors",
                    "Size": "6.47 inches, 102.8 cm2 (~88.6% screen-to-body ratio)",
                    "Resolution": "1080 x 2340 pixels, 19.5:9 ratio (~398 ppi density)",
                    "Protection": ["DCI-P3",
                        "HDR10"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

}

currently i do have a simple code but it doesn't return complete list of my "mobile"
here is my sample object

```
class Phone (
val mobile: PhoneList
)

data class PhoneList (
    val id: String,
    val device: DeviceInfo?
)

data class DeviceInfo (
    val device_name: String
)
```

thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Is the id and device structure in mobile to be array type ?
Use [ ] to include.
Ref :https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: Your JSON format is wrong. I think this is correct. ( https://jsonblob.com/9fdaceb0-e9aa-11e9-8fdc-05b2e5068c3a ).

Answer (score 9):

1. Browser the website https://app.quicktype.io/
2. Paste your JSON data to left column.
3. Select the Source Type -> JSON
4. Select the Serialization framework -> Just Types
5. Choose your language you want(Kotlin)

You will get the model class type.

```
class Phone (
    val mobile: List<Mobile>
)

data class Mobile (
    val id: String,
    val device: Device
)

data class Device (
    val deviceName: String,
    val price: String,
    val rating: String,
    val category: String,
    val description: Description
)

data class Description (
    val network: List<String>,
    val launch: Launch,
    val body: Body
)

data class Body (
    val dimension: String,
    val weight: String,
    val build: String,
    val network: List<String>,
    val display: Display
)

data class Display (
    val type: String,
    val size: String,
    val resolution: String,
    val protection: List<String>
)

data class Launch (
    val announcedDate: String,
    val status: String
)
```

Comment: it good, though since I am using Gson, it always gets null value

Comment: Ok. I just want to share this method. It could be used on any language you want. Not just Android.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-
2. Restart Android studio
3. Right-click on folder where you want your model class and select `New` > `Kotlin data class File from JSON`
4. Past the JSON content and click OK
5. Once you have the JSON mapped to model class you can use `map` to get the list of devices out.
   It will generate the model class automatically (essential timesaver).

Comment: hi, already installed and tried. but the problem is, it only returns one device only.

val mobileList = gson?.fromJson(json, PhoneList::class.java)

Comment: @MaChee Neraid, look at pt. 5 (note the [].class)

Comment: val mcArray = gson.fromJson(json, Array<Mobile>::class.java)     , but the result this "Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Comment: Yes, because your JSON is not of type List (it's Object), You need to parse from JSON to object and then you can map the devices out.